# Condition for relation records

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Hello i'm trying to return all records that have and doesn't have records in other table.

This is my relationship

Model Product:

```
public function productsale(): HasMany{
    return $this->hasMany(ProductSale::class);
}
```

Model ProductSale:

```
public function product(): BelongsTo{
    return $this->belongsTo(Product::class);
}
```

The function i'm trying to return records:

```
public function filterProductsPagination($page = 1, $limit, Request $request)
{
    $listcat = array();
    if ($request->child == "all") {
        $category = Category::where([['slug', '=', $request->parent], ['status', '=', 1]])->first();
        array_push($listcat, $category->id);
        $cat_child = $category->children;
        foreach ($cat_child as $s1) {
            array_push($listcat, $s1->id);
        }
    } else {
        $category = Category::where([['slug', '=', $request->child], ['status', '=', 1]])->first();
        array_push($listcat, $category->id);
    }
    $offset = ($page - 1) * $limit;
    $brands = json_decode($request->brands);
    if (count($brands) != 0) {
        $products = Product::with('brand','productstore','productsale')->where('status', 1)->whereIn('category_id', $listcat)->whereIn('brand_id', $brands)->offset($offset)->limit($limit)->get();
        $products_all = Product::where('status', 1)->whereIn('category_id', $listcat)->whereIn('brand_id', $brands)->get();
    } else {
        $products = Product::with('brand','productstore','productsale')->where('status', 1)->whereIn('category_id', $listcat)->offset($offset)->limit($limit)->get();
        $products_all = Product::where('status', 1)->whereIn('category_id', $listcat)->get();
    }


    return response()->json(
        ['success' => true, 'message' => 'Success', 'data' => $products, 'data_total' => $products_all],
        200
    );
}
```

I have tried to make a condition for them but if date_begin larger than current date it doesn't return that record.
What i expected is return records that have or doesn't have record in other table, if it have, return the first sale record that date_begin <= current_date and date_end >= current_date.

Comment: Can you please define what are the models , and what are the relationships between the models.